# display an icon string from environment variables file using flutter

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm working on a flutter project and I have an icon in my environment variable file like that :`ICON1=Icon(IconData(U+0E318))`
And I want to display it in my bottom navigation bar using this code :

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: dotenv.env['ICON1'] ?? 'ICON1 not found',
            label: 'Accueil',
          ),
```

But it gave me this error : `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'`. Is there a way I can display it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The BottomNavigationBarItem expects a Widget in the icon.

So, You can do it by using Icon class constants according to [official Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html#constants).

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(IconData(int.parse(Icon(dotenv.env['ICON1'] ?? 0xf04b6 ), fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
        label: 'Accueil',
      ),
```

IF you already have `Icon(IconData(U+0E318))` in the `env` you can simply cast is as Icon  like

```
icon: dotenv.env['ICON1] as Icon
```

Comment: it still give me this error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'IconData' in type cast"

Comment: Not working my variable is all this string "Icon(IconData(U+0E318))" I can't place it inside another Icon

Comment: Thank you so much, but I tried it and it give me this error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Icon' in type cast"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all values stored in a .env file are loaded as string values,
So you can't just put it as a widget there.

What you can do is store the codePoint of an Icon, which you can in return use with the IconData constructor to get a IconData object.

Get a codePoint value of an Icon like this:

```
print(Icons.abc.codePoint);
```

Once you got the value, put it inside the .env file

And next time you load it, pass the value inside the int.parse() function

```
int codePoint = int.parse(dotenv.env['my_icon'])
```

And then you can use that icon like this:

```
icon: Icon(IconData(codePoint))
```